# How to synchronize random resets in two Ethernet Controllers (DP83816)?

Tags: ethernet

I use two Ethernet Controllers ([DP83816](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83816.pdf)) in a design which also has a CPLD. When the power is supplied, Ethernet chip undergoes a random reset and it resets the CPLD (XC95144XL) internally. Since I have two Ethernet chips the reset of these can be possibly at two different times which will screw up my design. Is there any way to synchronize these resets?

Comment: Like, supply power in a specific order?

Comment: You haven't given anywhere near enough information to answer this question. How are the three chips connected to each other? What is the CPLD doing? What exactly does "undergoes a random reset" mean, and how does this cause a CPLD reset?

Answer (score 1):

This depends slightly on what is being achieved by the reset. My thought would be to use a logic gate to reset the CPLD once both Ethernet controllers are ready (AND gate if active high, NOR gate if active low).

Alternatively, you could use a power on reset controller to hold all of the ICs in reset until power is stable.